# Opening the browser debugger fixes my CORS issue

Tags: javascript, cors

So I have this strange issue:

I have a CORS problem when I try to fetch PNG images through Javascript to generate a PDF file.
BUT this problem only occurs if my browser debugger is **not** displayed. If I Ctrl+Alt+I **before** loading my page, the problem is not encountered.

This is what I get when I don't open the debugger:

[image]

This is what I get when I open the debugger before loading the page:

[image]

The pdf I am generating correctly queries the PNGS.

For some reason, opening the browser debugger *before* sending my fetch request seems to fix a CORS issue.

I checked my front side and we insert CORS for all requests related to the URI I hit. This is just mind boggling.

Could it be the debugger impacting code timings? Or adding a "let cors go"?

This is the fecth code I use:

```js
fetch(data.src, {
        "mode": "cors",
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": [
            ["Accept", "image/*"]
        ],
        "credentials": "include"
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.arrayBuffer();
    })
    .then(function (buffer) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes having Chrome developer tools open (depending on the options you have selected) will change the default behaviors of your requests (for example caching) which can also affect CORS.

Do you have this checkbox checked?
[image]

Comment: Aww man, this is it. So this could be a cache issue? I can now reproduce the problem with the debugger opened. I'll come back if I get stuck, time to investigate

Comment: Yes since CORS uses HTTP requests and their headers, caching can affect it greatly. Do you have control over the server side you are requesting from also? Depending on the issue, sometimes it is more appropriate to fix the headers inside the server config. In your case you can probably modify the `fetch` call you are doing to pass in some argument that ignores caching

Comment: Yes, this is what I am contemplating now: passing a random ?timestamp=$date to see if this could force a CORS re-preflight

Comment: @Gui13 want to accept this answer or vote it up or anything?

Comment: All right Chris, it actually pointed me to the right direction: the request was cached and passed through for some reason.